# Break a string in to an array with conditions using array.reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to break a string up in to an array with a max of 15 characters per item in the array. I want to accomplish this with `array.reduce`. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Staring with this:

```
const str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit'
```

I want to get a result like this:

```
const result = ['Lorem ipsum', 'dolor sit amet', 'consectetur', 'adipiscing elit']
```

Comment: well, try actually using array reduce

Comment: why `reduce`? sounds just too complicated

Comment: `const result = str.split(' ').reduce((a,i)=>(a.length?(()=>{let n=a.length-1,s=a[n],l=s.length;((s+i).length<15)?a[n]+=' '+i:a.push(i)})():a.push(i),a),[]);`

Comment: For the record, also possible with regex. Very much not recommended, however - I just did this for fun: `/(?<=^|\s).{1,15}(?=\s|$)/g` match up to 15 characters but they have to be whole words, so it won't match the middle of a word, nor would it include a space before/after a word. `[...str.matchAll(regex)].flat()` produces the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each `reduce` iteration, concatenate with the last sentence and then compare the length to the maximum, if it exceed, add the new sentence, else override the last sentence with the concatenated

```js
const str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit'

const res = str.split(' ').reduce((acc, word) => {
  const lastSentence = acc.pop()
  const currentConcatnated = [lastSentence, word].filter(Boolean).join(' ')
  
  if (currentConcatnated.length > 15) {
    acc.push(lastSentence)
    acc.push(word)
  } else {
    acc.push(currentConcatnated)
  }
  
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(res)
```

Comment: That's it, thank you! Reduce has been difficult to wrap my head around for some reason.

Comment: @zero it's also difficult to me at the first time too, the main point I took away after lots of practice is to remember to return the accumulated value after each iteration

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more readable approach still using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). It avoids accessing the last element of `acc` if it's empty by asserting `lastIndex >= 0` to ensure it's not the first iteration.

```js
const str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit';
const result = str.split(' ').reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const lastIndex = acc.length - 1;
  const val = ' ' + cur;

  if (lastIndex >= 0 && acc[lastIndex].length + val.length <= 15) {
    acc[lastIndex] += val;
  } else {
    acc.push(cur);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another implementation using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) that showcases alternative tricks.

- The [nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) for extra safety.
- [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), so never mutates the array argument. It's not needed but it's a useful trick for other situations where mutations are inadvisable.

```js
const str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit';

const result = str.split(/\s+/); //split on any amount of whitespace
  .reduce((acc, word) => {
    //get the last item but start with an empty string if `acc` is empty
    const last = acc[acc.length - 1] ?? "";
    
    //construct the potential new entry and remove extra spaces from start/end
    const newLast = `${last} ${word}`.trim();
    
    if (newLast.length > 15) //if too long
      return acc.concat(word);    // just add the word as a new element
    
    return acc.slice(0, -1) //take everything but the last item
      .concat(newLast); //append the new element as last
  }, []);
  
console.log(result);
```

Also, an alternative implementation can be done just using a regular expression

```
/(?<=^|\s)\b.{1,15}\b(?=\s|$)/g
```

This will match up to 15 characters as long as they are form whole words, so it wouldn't match the middle of a word nor whitespace before or after words.

```js
const regex = /(?<=^|\s)\b.{1,15}\b(?=\s|$)/g;

const str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit';

const result = [...str.matchAll(regex)].flat();

console.log(result);
```

[See on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HF8No9/1)

Here is some examples of why it works:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit
^         ^^  ^
|_________||  |
    11     |  |
           |  |
           |  + -> the 15th character but the next symbol is not whitespace or the end of the line, so the match cannot end here
           + -> whitespace so the match cannot end here
```

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit
           ^^            ^
           ||____________|
           |      14
           |
           + -> the match cannot start on a whitespace and it also has to be preceded by whitespace
```